# Преобразование byte[] -> string -> byte[]

Tags: c#

Подскажите если не сложно.
Есть код:

```cs
string txt = "Hello World!!!+=_^%kl;sdfkljdfklgjdklff';kldfjg23459037652*(*^^&$%^#(";
byte[] data2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(txt);
string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data2);
byte[] data3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
Console.WriteLine(data2 == data3); // False
```

В итоге интересует преобразование `byte[] -> string -> byte[]`, при отсутствии изменений ожидаемое поведение `data2 = data3`, а в моем коде получается что это не так. Как я понимаю при преобразовании что-то теряется, но как этого избежать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Массивы по содержимому можно сравнить так, с помощью Linq.

```
Console.WriteLine(data2.SequenceEqual(data3));
```

Либо написать свой метод сравнения с использованием цикла.

Через `==` сравниваются только ссылки на экземпляры массивов, а так как экземпляры разные, выводится `False`. Содержимое при этом никак не учитывается. Другими словами, для массивов `==` вернет `true` только если массив сравнивается сам с собой.

```cs
byte[] array4 = array3;
Console.WriteLine(array3 == array4); // True
```

[Ссылочные и значимые типы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.16.php).

Comment: Благодарю с SequenceEqual все заработало.