# Применение метода Contains в зубчатом массиве

Tags: c#, массивы, .net

Не могу понять почему Contains не возвращает true.

```
int[][] c = new int[][] { new int[] { 1, 1 }, new int[] { 0, 4 } };

Console.WriteLine(c.Contains(new int[] { 1, 1 }));
```

Пожалуйста объясните почему такое происходит и как это обыграть без создания лишней энтропии кода.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: что происходит-то?

Comment: Contains возвращает false, хотя должен вернуть true

Comment: добавь это в вопрос.

Comment: Нет, не должен. По умолчанию массивы сравниваются по ссылке - новый массив - новая ссылка - результат `false`. Однако, можно передать вторым параметром `IEqualityComparer` в котором определить, как именно нужно сравнивать объекты

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1275251/373567 `int[] b = new int[] { 1, 1 }; WriteLine(c.Any(x => x.SequenceEqual(b)));`

Comment: Понял, всем спасибо!